# Setup local domain for private network without editing hosts files

Tags: networking, router, dns, wamp, bind

## The Problem

I host a local website at 192.168.1.2 using WAMP. My router is at 192.168.1.1 But i need a way to provide a hostname to this website. It is not feasible to edit the hosts file on each computer as there are around 120 computers on this networks and many other devices.

For eg: home.com should resolve to 192.168.1.2 on all the other computers.
        But i still need google.com to resolve using my ISP's DNS.

#### What I've Tried

I have tried maradns to no avial.
I think setting up a DNS server using BIND should do the trick. But i have no idea how to set it up on Windows 10 to resolve local hostnames and simultaneously use the ISP's DNS.

Trying to flash the router with OpenWRT or DD-WRT will not work either because the router is not supported.

So far i have installed BIND9 on the computer and also created a rndc.key file. But i cannot find the named.conf file in /ect/ !

#### What I Need

I need to also be also running the dns server on the same Computer as my website ! So Bind is currently installed on the computer that serves the local WAMP server and the website.

#### What You Need To Know

I moved my website to the root www folder. So the website is located at 192.168.1.2 and the WAMP configuration page is password protected at 192.168.1.2/admin

I have never used BIND9 before.

The computer is located at a private college and i only have permission to leave one computer on which is why i need both the dns and the website on the same server.

Comment: You have research to do.  DNS is not a simple service though everyone coming on here fresh thinks it is... it is a distributed global database, nothing simple about it.  In a browser, on your favorite search site, type in "DNS Book".  Buy or check-out and read any of those.  Then come back here with specific questions.

Comment: Check with your IT dept. There may already be a DNS on the network somewhere

Answer (score 0):

bit dodgy installing DNS on same PC, is likely to create issues in future.

Also issue of using 192.168 as so many devices use it.

So perhaps consider using on of the limtited 172.16. or class A 10.x.x.x subnets and use your router to make sure traffic goes where it should.

Comment: I know but the campus only has one router and is mainly wired connection. So no problem with that. I need a proper solution.

Comment: 192.168. is a private network address giving 65,536 IP addresses, just like 10. but 10. gives you more available addresses